# Why is my Java ArrayList adding objects, but then prints empty?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 3 classes: an `Item` class, a `Pantry` class (where items are stored) and a `ReadFile` class (where I read items from a text file).

I will read the items from the text file and then these items will become objects in my `Item` class, and then I want to store the object items in an `ArrayList` in my `Pantry` class.

The text file reads like this:

```
Salami   2  3  4
Fish  1  6  2
Jerky 3  1  6
```

Very simple.  `String -tab- int -tab- int -tab- int`

```
import java.util.Comparator;

/** Item class
 * An object
 */
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int value;
    private int weight;
    private int avail;

    /**
     * Item(String name, int value, int weight, int avail)
     * Initializes attributes
     */
    public Item(String name, int value, int weight, int avail)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.avail = avail;
    }
//Just contains Getters/Setters for each attribute

}
```

`ReadFile` class:

```
/**ReadFile class
 * Class that reads data from a .txt file
 */

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


public class ReadFile{

    private static BufferedReader reader;
    private static BufferedWriter writer;
    private static String currentLine;


    //Following code is from:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VrtranTJnc
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        File inFile;
        JButton open = new JButton();
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
        jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        jfc.setDialogTitle("Knapsack Program");

        if (jfc.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            //end code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VrtranTJnc
            inFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Input File Chosen: " + inFile);

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));


            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("The file was not found");
                System.exit(0);
            }


            try {

                Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);

//Add lines from text file to Item object
                while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){  
                    String name = input.next() ;
                    int value = input.nextInt();
                    int weight = input.nextInt();
                    int avail = input.nextInt();

                    Item newItem = new Item(name, value, weight, avail);

                    newItem.setName(name);
                    newItem.setValue(value);
                    newItem.setWeight(weight);
                    newItem.setAvail(avail);

                    //Add this new Item to the array of items.
                    Pantry p = new Pantry();
                    p.addItemToArray(newItem);
                }

                reader.close();
                input.close();

            }catch (IOException e2){
                System.out.println("The file was not found");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            Pantry p2 = new Pantry(); //just for testing
            p2.printArray();  //just for testing


    }
}
```

And now the `Pantry` class:

```
**Pantry class
 * A collection class that stores items into an array
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Pantry  {

    private ArrayList<Item> itemArray = new ArrayList<>();


    /** getItemArray()
     * @return itemArray  Returns the arraylist of items
     */
    public ArrayList<Item> getItemArray() {
        return itemArray;
    }

    /**
     * setItemArray(ArrayList<Item> itemArray)
     * @param itemArray
     */
    public void setItemArray(ArrayList<Item> itemArray) {
        this.itemArray = itemArray;
    }


    /** addItemToArray(Item item)
     * item = an object
     * Add Item to array
     * @return 
     */
    public void addItemToArray (Item item)  {
            itemArray.add(item);


        System.out.println("ADDED: " + itemArray);//just for testing  - looks like it added the items.

        }


    /** toString()
     * @return  One string representing all of list
     */
    public String toString()    {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.size(); i++)  {
            result += itemArray.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void printArray() {         

        Pantry p = new Pantry();
        System.out.println("Print Array: " + p.getItemArray());
        System.out.println("Print Array string: " + p.toString());
//Both of these print as empty.
        }    

    }

}
```

My print results look like this:

```
ADDED: [Salami  2   3   4   ]
ADDED: [Fish    1   6   2   ]
ADDED: [Jerky   3   1   6   ]
Print Array: []
Print Array string:
```

Can anyone help me see why the arraylist is printing empty?  I'm sure it's something simple, but I am just not seeing it.

Comment: Why are you creating a new Pantry object in `printArray` ? You haven't added any items to that so of course it will be empty

Comment: Thank you, Dana!  I took that out now per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this code

```
 //Add this new Item to the array of items.
 Pantry p = new Pantry();
 p.addItemToArray(newItem);
```

is scoped within the `loop`

declare it before the `loop` and remove the other `Pantry`

```
        // Pantry p2 = new Pantry(); //remove
        p.printArray();  //change to `p`
```

Also do you not create a new `Pantry` in `printArray` - `printArray` is already a method of `Pantry`

**edit**

Also, in `printArray` you need to be dealing/printing with `itemArray`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!  It's not printing yet, but it seems to be storing the items better!  Printing:   ADDED: [Salami 2 3 4 ]
ADDED: [Salami 2 3 4 , Fish 1 6 2 ]
ADDED: [Salami 2 3 4 , Fish 1 6 2 , Jerky 3 1 6 ]
Print Array: []

Comment: Did you remove the `Pantry` Object from `printArray` as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I made all the suggested changes and it's working well now!  Thank you for getting me past this point I was stuck on for hours!!

Comment: That's good, if my answer helped please consider to upvote and/or accept

Comment: Thank you very much